# (Laravel) Get the difference of current date and given date in DB::raw

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5.7

I tried the code below, but didn't work.

```
 $susbcribers = DB::table('subscribers')
      ->select(
            DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(Carbon::now()->subDate(subscribers.expired_at), '%d') as days_left"),
      )->get();
```

I just want to get the **days left**, but now I'm stuck with this. I am just beginner of Laravel, somebody help me of this, would appreciate any suggestion/advice, thanks in adv..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick.

```
$susbcribers = DB::table('subscribers')
    ->select(DB::raw("DATEDIFF(now(), expired_at) as days_left"))
    ->get();
```

Comment: it gives me an error "1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'"  Sir

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer. Can you give the updated one a try?